# ELSE IF 2 errors in Tableau Prep

Tags: tableau-desktop

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF9Zc.png)

`IF [Application Building] = "ALHVL" THEN "AL - Statewide" ELSEIF "ALANN" THEN "AL - Statewide" ELSEIF "ALBIR" THEN "AL - Statewide" ELSEIF "ALDEC" THEN "AL - Statewide" ELSEIF "ALDOT" THEN "AL - Statewide" ELSEIF "ALENT" THEN "AL - Statewide" ELSE "ORHLL" THEN "OR - Portland" END`

Error: Invalid Syntax

Expected different text

Comment: You can either repeat the “[Application Building] = “ part of the phrase each time after every ELSEIF — or you can use a CASE expression instead which is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CASE expression

```
CASE [Application Building]
  WHEN “ALHVL” THEN “Al - Statewide”
  WHEN “ALANN” THEN “Al - Statewide”
  …
END
```

Or if there is fixed pattern in your, say the first two letters being the state abbreviation, then take advantage of it, say

```
CASE LEFT([Application Building], 2)
  WHEN “AL” THEN “AL - Statewide”
  WHEN “OR” THEN “OR - Statewide”
  …
END
```

Or even simpler

```
LEFT([Application Building], 2) + “ - Statewide”
```

Or even better split into two calculated fields that can be reused.

1. Define **[State]** as `LEFT([Application Building], 2)`
2. And Define **[Location Label]** as `[State] + “ - Statewide”`

Then you can reuse the [State] field to make maps easily

Bottom line, if you find yourself typing (or pasting) nearly the same redundant thing over and over, slow down, take a minute and look for a smarter way to avoid that redundant effort. Its usually well worth the small effort and pays off down the road.

Comment: Unfortunately CASE does not work in my tableau Prep

Comment: The expression language is the same in Tableau Prep and Tableau Desktop, so CASE works. Show an example.