# ELSE IF statement in Prep "Valid" but data is blank. Example Below

Tags: tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I am connecting my tableau server to my prep flow, everything looks good! However, once I want to create a new column with a calc field (a column not in my original data source) the formula shows up as "Valid" but the columns are blank. The formula is below, its about 1000 rows, but i just copied and pasted the first few lines here. Any reason what is going on?

IF [Application Building] = "ALHVL" THEN "AL - Statewide"

ELSEIF [Application Building] = "ALANN" THEN "AL - Statewide"

ELSEIF [Application Building] = "ALBIR" THEN "AL - Statewide"

ELSEIF [Application Building] = "ALDEC" THEN "AL - Statewide"

ELSEIF [Application Building] = "NYHOR" THEN "NY - Other"

ELSEIF [Application Building] = "NYJAM" THEN "NY - Other"

END

[Sample In Prep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vkbZ.png)

Comment: Most likely it's because the field "[Application Building]" doesn't contain any of the values in your list.  In particular, you might need to trim the field to eliminate leading or trailing spaces before you compare it to your values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ELSE IF 2 errors in Tableau Prep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72578448/else-if-2-errors-in-tableau-prep)

Answer (score 0):

From above observation we can say it's due to leading or trailing spaces, we can eliminate by using TRIM function. Still have the issue, share a sample data to get into more details.